# I dont know why my `max-width: 470px` media query isnt working

Tags: css, media-queries

I do not know what to do for it to work. I have been trying to make some stuff more specific and others more generalised yet it isnt working.

Please check my code and any advice or help is much appreciated 
(it isn't letting me post it 'cause its mostly code so im just gonna put letters)
kkkkkkkkkkk
kkkkkkkkkkk
kkkkkkkkkkk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Secret Agent Supply Inc.</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/reset.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="company background-black">
      <div class="nine-w container">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-5/secret-agent-supply/resources/images/logo.png">
        <span>SECRET AGENT SUPPLY INC.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner">
      <div class="nine-w">
        <div class="banner-content background-black">
          <h2>NEW ARRIVAL</h2>
          <h1>SPORT BIKES AND MOTORCYCLES</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <div class="nine-w">
        <ul class="desktop">
          <li>Eyewear</li>
          <li>Apparel</li>
          <li>Gadgets</li>
          <li>Vehicles</li>
          <li>Classes</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="mobile">
          <li>Menu</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="images nine-w">
        <div class="image-item">
          <div class="image-div">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-5/secret-agent-supply/resources/images/pen.png">
          </div>
          <span class="background-black">Exploding Pen</span>
        </div>

        <div class="image-item">
          <div class="image-div">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-5/secret-agent-supply/resources/images/watch.png">
          </div>
          <span class="background-black">Cellular Watch</span>
        </div>

        <div class="image-item hide">
          <div class="image-div">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-5/secret-agent-supply/resources/images/glasses.png">
          </div>
          <span class="background-black">Thermal Glasses</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="below nine-w">
        <div class="below-images">
          <span class="background-black">Location</span>
          <p>-47.346436, 84.32354</p>
        </div>

        <div class="below-images">
          <span class="background-black">Location</span>
          <p>0800 - 1800</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="background-black">
      <div class="nine-w">Copyright Secret Agent Supply Inc.</div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.nine-w{
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-black{
  background-color: black;
}

 .company .nine-w{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.66rem 0;
 }

.company img{
  height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
}

.company span{
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.banner{
  height: 25rem;
  background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/freelance-1/unit-5/moto.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.banner-content{
  max-width: 20rem;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 9rem;
}

h2{
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

h1{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

nav{
    background-color: firebrick;
}

nav ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: firebrick;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
}

.images{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.image-item{
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.image-div{
    height: 9rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 2rem 0;
}

.image-item img{
  max-width: 8rem;
}
.image-item span{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.below{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.below-images{
  width: 35%;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.below-images span{
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0 1rem 2rem;
}

.below-images p{
  color: black;
}

footer{
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

.mobile{
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 470px){
  .banner-content h2{
    font-size: 0.77rem;
  }

  .banner-content h1{
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .banner-content{
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    top: 10rem;
  }

  .banner{
    height: 15rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  .hide{
    display: none;
  }

  .image-item{
    width: 47%;
  }

  .desktop{
    display: none;
  }

  .mobile{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .banner-content h1{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

i expected for the media query to work when making my screen 470px or smaller, yet it isnt

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries are in the wrong order - just reverse their order: `max-width: 470px` should be *after*  `max-width: 1024px`. The way you have them now, the second one will overwrite the first one, because whatever is less than 470px wide is also less than 1024px wide.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I've set the background color of your banner-content to red in this example. It will work if your viewport width is less than 470px;

```
.banner-content{
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    top: 10rem;
    background: red
}
```

https://codepen.io/seyyedmojtaba72/pen/QRYEjd

Comment: Are you trying it on a phone or screen width below 470px?
you can try it using inspect tools of your browser.